# Shortcut does not work for firefox addon

Tags: firefox-addon, xul, shortcut

I've assigned a shortcut (ctrl+shift+z) for my firefox addon menu item by following code in xul file
but unfortunately it does not work. what is the problem?

```
  <keyset id="mainKeyset">
    <key id="key_convert" key="z" modifiers="accel shift"/>
  </keyset>

  <menupopup id="menu_ToolsPopup"> 

        <menuitem id="myextension-toolsmenuitem" 
            label="My Extension" 
      key="key_convert" 
            insertbefore="sanitizeSeparator"
    oncommand="myextension.test()" />

</menupopup>
```

Comment: I'd have to check, but I think you need to tie the command to the key by actually making a `<command>` element, and setting its key attribute. Or maybe setting the command attribute of the `key` element. Something along those lines...

Comment: Yes you are right. I added oncommand="myextension.test()" to key tag inside keyset and it worked ;)

Answer (score 1):

(You should re-post the correct answer as a stackoverflow answer, otherwise the question is displayed in the 'unanswered' lists.)

You have to set `command` or `oncommand` on the [key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/key) element for the shortcut to do anything. I've updated the docs to say this more clearly.

Comment: Yes you are right. I added oncommand="myextension.test()" to key tag inside keyset and it worked ;)